# Initializing a variable based on an argument

Tags: php

I was looking for some Magento 2's code and something aroused my interest.

```
 public function install(\Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface $setup, \Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $installer = $setup;
        [...]
    }
```

Is there any purpose on initializing a variable based on an argument instead of using it directly?

$setup is never used anymore and as far as I know I doubt this will be used as a copy.

I look for some other repos and code and I found that many people tend to do that.

Comment: No there's no reason for it. It's probably due to the history of the code, maybe an earlier version needed two different variables.

Comment: I see lots of code where people assign a local variable from a parameter for no good reason.